# Alternative proof: show that any metrizable space $X$ is normal - Part 1

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces, alternative-proof, separation-axioms

**There is a [proof online](http://math.gmu.edu/~tlim/metricnormal.pdf) that shows that all metric spaces are normal. The proof is as follows**

[image]

However, it has the additional baggage of needing to show that $d(x,A)$ is continuous and $U,V$ are open.

**Can we do make it even simpler using the following:**

> - Let $C, D$ be disjoint closed sets in $X$, $d$ be the metric that generates topology on $X$.
> - Define the set to set distance $d(C,D) = \inf\{d(c,d)| c \in C, d \in    D\}$.
> - Then take $r = d(C,D). r > 0$ since $C,D$ are disjoint.
> - Let $U = \bigcup_{x \in C} B_{\frac{r}{2}}(x), V = \bigcup_{y \in D}    B_{\frac{r}{2}}(y)$ are disjoint open sets containing $C, D$
>     respectively.

Is this good enough as an alternative proof?

Comment: Your "proof" is not simpler, it's more complicated: it has the additional baggage of taking unions. In the simple (and correct) proof you quote, you do have to know that $d(x,A)$ is continuous (hint: triangle inequality), but once you know it's continuous, it doesn't take much more to see that $d(x,B)-d(x,A)$ is continuous and so $U=\{x:d(x,B)-d(x,A)\gt0\}$ is open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s not necessarily true that $d(C,D)>0$ for disjoint closed sets $C$ and $D$. As a counterexample, take $C$ to be the $x$-axis in $\Bbb R^2$ and $D$ to be the graph of the hyperbola $xy=1$; then $C$ and $D$ are closed, $C\cap D=\varnothing$, and $d(C,D)=0$.

Comment: But we know that since $C,D$ are disjoint, there must be a small distance between them right? How can we produce such distance $r$ (without needing to use $d(C,D)$)?

Comment: @BeachedWhale: No, the distance between them can be $0$, as in the example that I gave here. You can get another example by replacing $D$ by the graph of $y=e^x$, for instance: again $$\inf\{d(x,y):x\in C\text{ and }y\in D\}=0\;.$$

Comment: Hmm..let me dig into the original proof and see why that worked

Comment: @BeachedWhale: Even if there are points of $C$ and $D$ arbitrarily close together, as in my examples, so that $d(C,D)=0$, it’s still true that every point of the space is either closer to $C$ than to $D$, closer to $D$ than to $C$, or equidistant from $C$ and $D$, and that exactly one of these must be the case.